# Android - Display content in SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, slidingmenu

I’m using a slidingtablayout with 3 tabs. I’m trying to display a image from a url in the first tab.

I tried loading the image on a single view and it worked fine.

Here is the xml for my first tab (activity_first.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=“myproject.FirstTab”>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="TEST LOADING IMAGE"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java for first tab (FirstTab.java):

```
public class FirstTab extends ActionBarActivity {
    Bitmap b;
    ImageView img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        information info = new information();
        info.execute("");
    }

    public class information extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://si.wsj.net/public/resources/images/BN-BY925_mag041_OZ_20140318165119.jpg");
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            img.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my fragment (LayoutInflater.java):

```
public class LayoutInflater extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first,container,false);
        return v;

    }
}
```

The result of the above is only the textview being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.needed_icon)

or if you need text with images you need to add this class to your Activity

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
.............
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageResId[position]);
        image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return sb;
    }
}
```

and then 
    `ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new             SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
            MainActivity.this));`

details: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go back to the documentation and read up on how Activities and Fragments work. I'm saying this to be offensive but rather because you have quite a few errors in your code, which makes me suspect that you have misunderstood some of the core concepts.

First of all, the layout your inflating in your Activity (that's what you do in `setContentView()`) and your fragment already contains text for your TextView. That's why the text is shown.

Your AsyncTask should also return the bitmap in `onDoInBackground` and so that it gets passed in as an argument in `onPostExcecute` (insted of the string you have now).

You say you have a SlidingTabsLayout, but there is no SlidingTabsLayout in your layout, so how can you have tabs?

Your fragment never loads the image (this is done in the FirstTab activity). That's why it's never shown.